# How to throttle jdbc data read in spark?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

In my spark job, I am reading from my MySQL data source since I am pulling such large data in a short duration, the CPU spikes of my MySQL. I want to slow down the data read speed so my db is not overloaded. Increase or decreasing partition will not matter since it will just divide into smaller into bigger chunks but it is essentially still reading bulk data in parallel.

Spark JDBC read code

```
spark
              .read()
              .options(options)
              .jdbc(
                  "URL",
                  "table",
                  dbConfig.getPartitioningColumn(),
                  lowebound,
                  upperBound,
                  numbOfPartitions,
                  new Properties())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce the size of the data by not reading a whole table. Instead passing table name and reading whole data, you can simply run query which does some aggregations or filtering that returns only required data. This will make your execution faster.

```
spark.read 
  .format("jdbc") 
  .option("query", "<query>") 
  .option("numPartitions",5) 
  .......
  .......
  .load()
```

Comment: I dont want to make my execution faster. I want to make it slower but I want to read whole data